# How to start particle from skybox

Tags: unity, particles

I'm trying to create a lightning particle system but I want to make the top of the particles at the skybox and the bottom on the ground.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Yes. But thunder is more of a hear thing than a see thing. If you mean lightning, how could a player notice the difference from an up to down strike compared to skybox to earth strike? What kind of camera do you have, what kind of view is the player having? Is it 2D or 3D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because the skybox isn't an *actual* 3d box with well-defined vertex coordinates. Geometrically-speaking, its distance from the camera is undefined. If you wanted to place a 3d game object *on* the skybox, it would need to have an infinite distance from the camera.

All you can do is make the starting point of the lightning bolt high enough that the player can not tell the difference.

Comment: I will try to make it high enough.